# How to make a SKPhysicsBody bounce back like a ball in iOS7 SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have set up my scene to contain an edge loop and a ball shaped object which is supposed to drop down and then bounce around until all its energy is gone.
However I can't seem to get the physics in SpriteKit to minimize restitution. The ball always drops and bounces back up only a few pixels.

My parameters are:

- world gravity = -4f
- body of the ball = circular with radius half the width of the frame
- restitution = 0f
- friction = 0f

I tweaked already gravity, mass of the ball and all other properties. My last idea is to apply a force to the ball as soon as it hits one of the borders but that just feels wrong. I should be able to simulate a bouncing ball.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stupid me. Restitution of 0 means: no bounciness at all. A value of "1" indicates "super bouncy".

Comment: Yup. For reference, here's the API docs on [restitution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013032-CH1-SW38).

Comment: set `linearDamping` to 0 for no air friction :)